# Can I run VueJS and NodeJS or related apps on Server that doesn't have NodeJS installed?

Tags: node.js, vue.js, vuejs2

So I'm new to Vuejs and doesn't know anything about npm, node, and other javascript apps.

I wanted to switch to VueJS so that I can take away from JQuery. Been using AdminLTE for my projects before.

I wanted to use [vue-admin](https://admin.vuebulma.com/#/buttons) now since it seems to address all of my needs. However, I have specific work area situations that seems to hinder learning Vue and other JS apps, these are:

1. The workspace folder (development) where I'm creating applications is hosted in the production server (Windows Server).
2. I think NodeJS isn't installed in the server
3. Adobe Coldfusion is used. I don't have a local server, so the production server is used when developing.

Question:

1. Will the production server run the app built with vue-admin even if the production server doesn't have NodeJS installed? (I have NodeJS locally).
2. I need to use Coldfusion for the logic of the application, specifically I'm using CFWheels right now and vue-admin for Frontend and UX. Is it possible? The application I'm making is closely related to parts of an ERP system.
3. Any pointers on how I could do this?

Comment: Vue is a client side library. It has nothing to do with the server unless you are using SSR (you aren't).

Comment: Yeah, I can use Vue by cdn, but i'm trying to create a project with vue-admin, not only vuejs, given the scenario I have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. Most likely you will need NodeJS locally to make your development life a bit easier.

You can simply include Vue in your project with a script tag or your can use a buildtool like Webpack to enable you to write ES6 and use a module system.

If you go with the latter it still exports as plain ES5 allowing you to use it on your server without any problem since all of this is code which runs on the clients machine, not on your server.

As you can see the requirements for this project have a big bold headline with: 'Development'.

https://github.com/vue-bulma/vue-admin#development

You don't need any of the requirements in production.

Comment: I downloaded it locally and tried to run by the nodejs server and it worked. When I tried to copy the whole directory in our production server it didn't.

Also, I don't know how can I extract just the css/js files I need to be able to put it into the CFWheels and possibly create an application (an MVC Framework written in Coldfusion)

Comment: You will have to be a little bit more concrete than this for other to understand what you mean: `I downloaded it locally and tried to run by the nodejs server and it worked`.

Comment: I tried to run it via NodeJS server in my local PC and it worked. I was able to navigate to the page (localhost:8080) in the browser and see the admin-vue page.

Next, I copied the whole directory into the production server which does not have NodeJS installed, and opened the webpage served by Coldfusion/IIS but it didn't worked. Maybe, some files are just to be copied from the whole directory which I'm not sure, or if there are npm commands I should do to extract to have a working template that I can apply to CFWheels.

Comment: You have to actually build the project with Webpack and move the built files over to your server, you can clearly see the output directory for the build files here: https://github.com/vue-bulma/vue-admin/blob/master/config/index.js#L10 This is the path where your files will be created at with Webpack when you run `npm run build`

Comment: You are a lifesaver! Do you know how can I have a dist folder if I run npm run dev instead?
The thing is that the project I am working will be on a subdirectory of a URL once it is implemented. When I tried to load the contents of the dist folder, I have to make some adjustments to the HTML links. And worse, the icons are not showing. I can't configure the links because it is compressed.

Comment: `npm run *` commands are available in the `package.json` you can view which command uses which files. It would be a matter of adjusting the right config files here: https://github.com/vue-bulma/vue-admin/tree/master/build